# Do I need database for react-redux in order to store users?

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, html, react-redux

I am working on a webapp project that has a sign up and sign in to dashboard using react and redux. Do I still need database(MySQL/phpmyadmin) to store my user profiles or does redux have libraries for saving users?

This is for a website/web application I'm trying to develop on siteground hosting

Comment: Yes, you still need database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to store the information about your users somewhere on your server. Redux will be running on the client side, and that is not where you want the information be stored.

So either you will need to install a database on your server or use a service like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).